# Display latest or upcoming event record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an events table:

```
EventID     Name        StartDate
1           Alpha       2016-07-01
2           Bravo       2016-11-01
3           Charlie     2017-03-01
4           Delta       2017-06-01
5           Echo        2017-09-01
```

I would like to display the upcoming event from the current date using this SQL statement:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Events WHERE StartDate < GETDATE() ORDER BY StartDate DESC
```

but it returns Event #2 (it should be #3). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your logic is wrong:

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.*
FROM Events e
WHERE e.StartDate > GETDATE()
ORDER BY StartDate ASC;
```

This gets the next event.  Your logic gets the previous event.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Events DATEDIFF(DAY,GETDATE(),StartDate) >= 0 ORDER BY StartDate ASC
```